# regex select only if string not start with //

Tags: regex

I have a text(code) like this

```
function a() {
    console.log(1);

    // console.log(1.5) <-- skip this select only non commented
    console.log(2)
}

console.log('go')
console.info('test')
```

I want to find only not commented console.logs using regex
I try this https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/23 but it not work for indented strings

The regex, for future reference, is:

```
^(?!(\/\/)\s)console\.(\w+).*
```

Comment: This isn't a python question... Or if it is, where is the python code?

Comment: I want to find in text using python

Comment: @cricket_007, the [regex] guidelines say to use a tag for the flavor of regex you're using.

Comment: The fact that this question is being downvoted while the answers are being upvoted is, truthfully, _very_ depressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
(?<!\/\/\s)console.*?\);?
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gs6mWA/2)**

Answer (score 2):

Your regex was close, after playing with it for a bit, I got this for a regex that appears to work for your example.

https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/25

Cheers.

This is the best regex I could come up with (I am not great with them myself). It matches a little more than it needs to, but it will never match a line with `//console.log('stuff');`

https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/29

Comment: This matches `// console.log(1.5)`. (Note that there is no whitespace before `//`)

Comment: @siam's answer (and mine) will still match for `//console.log(1.5)` which is probably undesireable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex : https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/28

The code
A `\s*` is added before the `console` to match words that have an indentation.

```
^(?!\/\/)\s*console\.(\w+).*
```

Comment: The lookahead in your regex doesn't achieve anything, you might as well remove it.